# How do you gift in-app purchases

Tags: android, ios

I am building a website for a client that is promoting an App on Kickstarter. As one of the rewards this client wants to reward sponsors with in-app purchases. I have searched Apple and posted on other forums but I can't find out if this is possible and if it is possible, how it is done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a promo-code dialog inside your app to do that, then send promo-codes to your Kickstarter users.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think It's possible.
[Here's](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2850372?hl=en-GB) the only Google documentation I could find.

You could make the app free for a short period until all backers have their copy and then raise the price but non backers will be able to download it too.

It would be possible however to use the [alpha/beta functionality](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en-GB) in the Google Play store to release the app to backers who have joined specific circles setup by you. I don't know if Google would have a problem with you using it like this.

It might be possible to distribute the app outside of the Play Store but I suspect that will become a big support problem as users struggle to get the app installed and keep it up to date.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS part we haven't this functionality with Store Kit. This framework was created to securely process payments from users. You don't need to work with payments. Just deliver some product or an extra functionality to user with promo code. Implement a dialogue in your app where user can enter his code, send this code to your server, check it and give an access for user, if code was right. That's all you need. After making the product available, your app needs to make a persistent record of the "purchase" like you do with normal in-app purchases.